# wp_remote_post() check failed using Algolia

Tags: wordpress, algolia

Have installed the Algolia plugin for my site but when it tries to run the test, it always fails with no (to me) helpful information as to why. The error message is:

```
Array
(
[headers] => Requests_Utility_CaseInsensitiveDictionary Object
    (
        [data:protected] => Array
            (
                [server] => nginx/1.10.0 (Ubuntu)
                [date] => Wed, 28 Sep 2016 09:20:36 GMT
                [content-type] => text/html; charset=UTF-8
                [expires] => Wed, 11 Jan 1984 05:00:00 GMT
                [cache-control] => no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0
                [x-frame-options] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => SAMEORIGIN
                        [1] => DENY
                    )

                [location] => https://www.myhost.co.uk/directory/
                [strict-transport-security] => max-age=15768000; includeSubDomains; preload
                [x-content-type-options] => nosniff
            )

    )

[body] => 
[response] => Array
    (
        [code] => 302
        [message] => Found
    )

[cookies] => Array
    (
    )

[filename] => 
[http_response] => WP_HTTP_Requests_Response Object
    (
        [response:protected] => Requests_Response Object
            (
                [body] => 
                [raw] => HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Server: nginx/1.10.0 (Ubuntu)
Date: Wed, 28 Sep 2016 09:20:36 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: close
Expires: Wed, 11 Jan 1984 05:00:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Location: https://www.myhost.co.uk/directory/
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=15768000; includeSubDomains; preload
X-Frame-Options: DENY
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff


                [headers] => Requests_Response_Headers Object
                    (
                        [data:protected] => Array
                            (
                                [server] => Array
                                    (
                                        [0] => nginx/1.10.0 (Ubuntu)
                                    )

                                [date] => Array
                                    (
                                        [0] => Wed, 28 Sep 2016 09:20:36 GMT
                                    )

                                [content-type] => Array
                                    (
                                        [0] => text/html; charset=UTF-8
                                    )

                                [expires] => Array
                                    (
                                        [0] => Wed, 11 Jan 1984 05:00:00 GMT
                                    )

                                [cache-control] => Array
                                    (
                                        [0] => no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0
                                    )

                                [x-frame-options] => Array
                                    (
                                        [0] => SAMEORIGIN
                                        [1] => DENY
                                    )

                                [location] => Array
                                    (
                                        [0] => https://www.myhost.co.uk/directory/
                                    )

                                [strict-transport-security] => Array
                                    (
                                        [0] => max-age=15768000; includeSubDomains; preload
                                    )

                                [x-content-type-options] => Array
                                    (
                                        [0] => nosniff
                                    )

                            )

                    )

                [status_code] => 302
                [protocol_version] => 1.1
                [success] => 
                [redirects] => 0
                [url] => https://www.myhost.co.uk/wp-admin/admin-post.php
                [history] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [cookies] => Requests_Cookie_Jar Object
                    (
                        [cookies:protected] => Array
                            (
                            )

                    )

            )

        [filename:protected] => 
        [data] => 
        [headers] => 
        [status] => 
    )

)
```

I can't work out from this where the issue is - the 302 code looks OK but I'm not sure what is happening that is causing the script to fail.

If I load the URL in a browser or using Postman, I get a 200 status code. Curl is enabled and working on my server so I'm not sure what the issue could be.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Hi there,

It appears that when triggering the url from your server it tries to redirect it.
Do you have HTTPS + HTTP?

Comment: It tries to redirect to https://www.myhost.co.uk/directory/ ? Does that ring a bell?

Comment: @rayrutjes I do have HTTPS and HTTP but HTTP just redirects straight to HTTPS and the Nginx config level. I do have a directory installed, which is one of the things I'm trying to index with Algolia. Not sure of what other tests I can try to replicate it!

Answer (score 2):

I don't know why (and someone might like to tell me that but I'll email the Algolia team about it too) but I changed line 75 of /search-by-algolia-instant-relevant-results/includes/admin/class-algolia-admin.php `redirection => 0,` to `redirection => 1,` and it worked fine.

Went through a couple other files (/search-by-algolia-instant-relevant-results/includes/class-algolia-task-queue-loopback-async.php and /search-by-algolia-instant-relevant-results/includes/libraries/wp-async-task/wp-async-task.php) and it seems to be working fine!

Comment: Thanks for investigating this one Ed. We recently disabled redirection because there should be no need for them. In your case I don't get why your initial request is redirected, but it really shouldn't be.

That being said, I think we will allow redirections to make sure it works for configuration as yours. 

Please let us know if you happen to investigate that redirection.

Opened an issue here: https://github.com/algolia/algoliasearch-wordpress/issues/322

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Just wanted to let you know that we have implemented a fix for this in version 1.2.0 of the plugin.

You can access the complete changelog for that version here: https://wordpress.org/plugins/search-by-algolia-instant-relevant-results/changelog/

Thanks again for reporting this in the first place ;)

Answer (score 0):

having just bumped into this issue myself I thought I'd take the effort to quickly write back.

My issue was resolved when I removed the directory privacy from the .htaccess file in the root that I'd applied earlier on in the day!

Cheers,
Richard.